# Writing A Text File To A Jar

Tags: java, jar, resources

I'm writing a program which 'builds' another. I plan to save the settings insite the generated jar file, but am having some trouble with writing to an external jar. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I don't completely understand.  Is the jar already generated and you're trying to add a file to it?  If that's the case, a jar is just a zip and you may be able to use a java library that modifies zips in order to do this.

Comment: Are you using the Jar API or calling it externally?  What problems are you having?

Comment: I dont know where to start.

Answer (score 2):

A jar is just a zip file so all you have to do is zip up your files and name the zip with a .jar extension.

One handy library to create jar archives is [Shrinkwrap](http://www.jboss.org/shrinkwrap) which allows you to put classes, resources, etc into jar files using a Java API

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to create a second jar, and write your own ClassLoader to load classes from that jar. A kind of plugin mechanism.